# Getting Error while trying to install jenkins on ubuntu 13 after installing java

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to set a jenkin server in ubuntu 13

I followed the following steps  and end up with error for some reason

Previously everything work well and due to some error i tried to uninstall java jdk and jenkin
and again followed the steps from the beginning

at some instance i mistakenly applied comment sudo apt autoremove to clean up everything and start a fresh installation

Following the steps

sudo apt-get install jenkins
sudo apt-get install ant

but went loaded got the following error
[image]

Any help

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007811/jenkins-critical-error-after-plugin-update

Comment: its about adding plugin and i am trying to install jenkin itself + it work fine during first attempt

Comment: tried out that workaround too but not succeed

Comment: @StephenC the link given as possible duplicate

Comment: @guny - Sigh ... There are TWO workarounds in the answers to that Question.  Which one did you try?

Comment: Workaround: delete $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/maven-plugin.jpi.pinned

Comment: i  uninstall everything and start from the beginning. then also showing the same error!!